# GTMSessionfetcher google drive UPLOAD to Google drive Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, gtmsessionfetcher

According to the documents published [here](http://http:/https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki#downloading-files), I can download and upload with GTMSessionFetcher.
And little bit further in the Documentation form the link I have a code for authorized download form google Drive:

```
GTLRQuery *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesGet queryForMediaWithFileId:fileID];
NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [service requestForQuery:query];
GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher =
  [service.fetcherService fetcherWithRequest:downloadRequest];

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *fetchError) {
  if (fetchError == nil) {
    // Download succeeded.
  }
}];
```

It works fine!

My question is: how do I upload with GTMSessionFetcher to Google Drive in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code from [Google Toolbox for Mac - Session Fetcher](https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher):

```
@interface GTMSessionUploadFetcher : GTMSessionFetcher

// Create an upload fetcher specifying either the request or the resume location URL,
// then set an upload data source using one of these:
//
//   setUploadFileURL:
//   setUploadDataLength:provider:
//   setUploadFileHandle:
//   setUploadData:

+ (instancetype)uploadFetcherWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                          uploadMIMEType:(NSString *)uploadMIMEType
                               chunkSize:(int64_t)chunkSize
                          fetcherService:(GTM_NULLABLE GTMSessionFetcherService *)fetcherServiceOrNil;

+ (instancetype)uploadFetcherWithLocation:(NSURL * GTM_NULLABLE_TYPE)uploadLocationURL
                           uploadMIMEType:(NSString *)uploadMIMEType
                                chunkSize:(int64_t)chunkSize
                           fetcherService:(GTM_NULLABLE GTMSessionFetcherService *)fetcherServiceOrNil;

- (void)setUploadDataLength:(int64_t)fullLength
                   provider:(GTM_NULLABLE GTMSessionUploadFetcherDataProvider)block;
```

The github code states that **`GTMSessionFetcher`** makes it easy for Cocoa applications to perform http operations. The fetcher is implemented as a wrapper on **`NSURLSession`**, so its behavior is asynchronous and uses operating-system settings on iOS and Mac OS X.

Hope this helps.